# dojox/checkedMultiSelect add option on top AS 'select all'

Tags: dojo

I am trying to populate the dojox/form/checkedMultiSelect with a top option named: 'select all'.
One way to do this is to use declare function to change the '_addOptionItem' function.
The problem is that this '_addOptionItem' function is using a declared object named: 'formCheckedMultiSelectMenu**Item**' inside the 'CheckedMultiSelect' widget, AND gives an error with: 'formCheckedMultiSelectMenuItem is not defined'.
How to fix this?
My JS code:

```
declare_CheckedMultiSelect: function(formCheckedMultiSelectItem){
        return declare(CheckedMultiSelect, {

            startup: function() {
                this.inherited(arguments);
                setTimeout(lang.hitch(this, function() {
                    this.dropDownButton.set("label", this.label);
                }));
            },

            _addOptionItem: function(item){
                var item;
                if(this.dropDown){
                    item = new formCheckedMultiSelectMenuItem({
                        option: option,
                        parent: this.dropDownMenu
                    });
                    c(item)
                    this.dropDownMenu.addChild(item);
                }else{
                    item = new formCheckedMultiSelectItem({
                        option: option,
                        parent: this
                    });
                    this.wrapperDiv.appendChild(item.domNode);
                }
                this.onAfterAddOptionItem(item, option);
            }

        });
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain more what are you trying to achieve here?? do you want to make select All checkbox ?? if you can put your example is jsfiddle.net

Comment: yes. that's what I meant.  
here is a jsfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/894af/744/

Comment: the error is clearly saying that formCheckedMultiSelectMenuItem is not defined and it is not defined when you want to create a new instance of formCheckedMultiSelectMenuItem, formCheckedMultiSelectMenuItem neeed to be available. where is it called from ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is working prototype of what you are trying to achieve http://jsfiddle.net/894af/750/ please feel free to ask any follow up question. it is done in different way, but what I simply did is:

1) when create the mutliselect get each check box after creating using

`onAfterAddOptionItem`

2) listen to the select all checkbox and then override the onclick fucntion and then change the selection of all the checkboxs, based on the selection of the checkbox.

```
if(option.value == "SA"){
            on(item, "click", function(evt){
          var optionsToSelect = checkedMultiSelect.getOptions();

            for(var i = 0 ; i < optionsToSelect.length;i++){

                if(optionsToSelect[i].value == "SA"){

                    if(optionsToSelect[i].selected){  
                        checkedMultiSelect.set("value",optionsToSelect);

                    }else{

                         checkedMultiSelect.set("value",[]);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

            }
```

Comment: thanx dori. 
I accept this as an answer, although I really wonder how to solve the undefined error.

Comment: thank you, I am not sure why you are getting the undefined error sometimes the widget have some bugs in it and you have to wait for the next dojo release or maybe raise a bug case. but this will do the job for now.